# Typescript item of an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array, like

```
Array[{id:0,name:"a"},{id:1,name:"b"}...]
```

I have an other array, let's call it `Array2`, in Array2 I want those items from `Array`where the `id = given number`.
I'm trying this with a function like:

```
saveActualComment() {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.postComments.length; i++) {
      if (this.postComments[i].postid = this.post.id) {
        this.actualComments.push(this.postComments[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Where `postCommets` is the `Array`, and `actualComments` is the `Array2`.
Problem is, that this function always gives me back the whole array, not only those items where the `Array.id` is the given number (`post.id`)

Comment: Have you tried to use compare operator instead of assigning value?

Comment: @yurzui not yet, but will give it a try

Comment: Yes, as mentioned you are assigning to `this.postComments[i].postid` instead of comparing its value. Use a double or triple equals instead, eg: `if (this.postComments[i].postid === this.post.id) { ... }`

Comment: @Skickpause not sure if typo but it should be `==` in the if clause.

Comment: @Ploppy It's a shame, but it's a typo

Comment: @Skickpause I think it happens to any dev at some point :D

Comment: @Ploppy Then I think I just Haven't drunk enough coffee to start coding yet :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (this.postComments[i].postid = this.post.id) {
        this.actualComments.push(this.postComments[i]);
      }
```

in above code
use == instead of =

```
this.postComments[i].postid == this.post.id
```

or you can do this

```
this.actualComments = this.postComments.filter((item) => item.postId === this.post.id);
```

Comment: Thank you :) So it was just a typo.., and thank you for the other solution, I haven't known that I can do this Array.filter

Comment: yeah you can do more then just filter.. look at this tutorial https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d